# Make the listbox clickable

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

I made a textbox in vb.net for a Windows Phone 8.

It works fine, but I want to make the listbox clickable.

If you push on the text, nothing happens.
Can someone help me please?
Here's my code:

**Xaml:**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.LijstRestaurants"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF386A06">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" TextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" Text="" Margin="0,48,0,552" Height="80" ></TextBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" FontSize="21" Height="580" Margin="0,100,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Restaurantnaam}" Width="440" Margin="10,15,0,0" Height="80"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Zoek je gewenste restaurant" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**VB.net:**

```
Partial Public Class LijstRestaurants
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
    Private lstRestaurants As List(Of ClassRestaurants) = Nothing
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(args As NavigationEventArgs)


        lstRestaurants = New List(Of ClassRestaurants)()
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "ABDIJ DER TRAPPISTEN" & vbNewLine & "Scheldemolenstraat Haven 1800, 9130 Beveren" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "ASTER-CAMPUS MELVEREN" & vbNewLine & "Antwerpsesteenweg 496, 2390 Malle" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "BAYER LILLO" & vbNewLine & "Retieseweg 111, 2440 Geel" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "CHR PELTZER LA TOURELLE" & vbNewLine & "Sint-jozefstraat 35, 2000 Antwerpen" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "CLINIQUE SAINT-JEAN" & vbNewLine & "Haven 1071 - Kapeldijk 40, 9130 Kallo" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "CPAS NIVILLES" & vbNewLine & "Minderbroedersstraat 5, 3800 Sint-Truiden" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "CUISINE CENTRALE CLINIQUE SAIN" & vbNewLine & "Vaartkaai 2, 2170 Merksem" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "DANONE N.V." & vbNewLine & "Rue Hauzeur de Simony 20, 4800 Verviers" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "ELECTRABEL KALLO" & vbNewLine & "Stiftstrasse 9, 4711 Astenet" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "ELECTRABEL KCD DOEL" & vbNewLine & "Haven 1992 Ketenislaan 2, 9130 Kallo" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "ELIA MERKSEM" & vbNewLine & "Huffengrasse 4/6, 4700 Eupen" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "ENI GAS & POWER" & vbNewLine & "Haven 507 Scheldelaan 420, 2040 Antwerpen" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "EUROPESE COMMISSIE IRMM" & vbNewLine & "Melverencentrum 111, 3800 Sint-Truiden" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "KARMEL BRUGGE" & vbNewLine & "Rue Samiette 70, 1400 Nivilles" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "KATHARINESTIFT" & vbNewLine & "Avenue Leopold Wiener 20, 1170 Brussel" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "LANXESS KALLO" & vbNewLine & "Lindestraat 3, 1540 Herne" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "MEALS ON WHEELS" & vbNewLine & "Sint-Jozefstraat 1A, 9041 Oostakker" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "MICROFIBRES EUROPE N.V." & vbNewLine & "Boulevard du jardin botanique 32, 1000 Brussel" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "MINDERBROEDERS" & vbNewLine & "Boulevard du jardin botanique 32, 1000 Brussel" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "O.C.M.W. HARELBEKE" & vbNewLine & "Lange Meire 56, 9270 Laarne" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "O.C.M.W. NINOVE" & vbNewLine & "Rue Guimard 1, 1040 Brussel" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "O.C.M.W. WIELSBEKE" & vbNewLine & "Hernieuwenstraat 15, 8710 Wielsbeke" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "O.C.M.C. WAREGEM - WZC DE MEERS" & vbNewLine & "Kapelaniestraat 2, 8953 Heuvelland-Wijtschate" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "O.C.M.W. HEUVELLAND ST MEDARD WZC." & vbNewLine & "Schakelstraat 41, 8790 Waregem" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "OUDE ABDIJ VAN DRONGEN V.Z.W." & vbNewLine & "Drongenplein 26, 9031 Drongen" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "RESIDENCE SAINTE-ANE" & vbNewLine & "Centrumlaan 173, 9400 Ninove" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "RUSTHUIS SINT-FELIX" & vbNewLine & "Vrijdomkaai 31, 8530 Harelbeke" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
            .Restaurantnaam = "SANKT-NIKOLAUS HOSPITAL" & vbNewLine & "Stationstraat 170, 3110 Rotselaar" _
        })
        lstRestaurants.Add(New ClassRestaurants() With { _
           .Restaurantnaam = "SINT-JOZEF INSTITUUT" & vbNewLine & "Ezelstraat 28, 8000 Brugge" _
       })
        Me.listBox.ItemsSource = lstRestaurants
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)
        If lstRestaurants IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.listBox.ItemsSource = lstRestaurants.Where(Function(w) w.Restaurantnaam.ToUpper().StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fiddling around with Buttons or Tapped Events you should simply subscribe to the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event of your ListBox which is fired every time you tap an element of it.

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- ... ->                 
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In your code behind you can catch this event and find out, which of your items (Restaurants) caused it.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem != null)
    {
        // This is your selected item:     
        ClassRestaurants selectedRestaurant = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ClassRestaurants;
        MessageBox.Show(selectedRestaurant.Restaurantnaam, "You selected:", MessageBoxButton.OK);                
    }
}
```

Sorry that it is C# code, but I am sure you can translate it into VB.net

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how can I get a different messagebox when I click on a different text? I think with this code, you get always the same message.

Comment: Have you tried it out? You should always get the name of the restaurant you selected. This is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah thanks! I have another question: I want to get the different opening hours if I click on a restaurant...Now, there's always the same messagebox with the name of the restaurant. Can you help me please?

Answer (score -1):

Add Tap event to TextBlock

Or replace TextBlock with Button and add click event and bind its Content to the text

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" FontSize="21" Height="580" Margin="0,100,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Restaurantnaam}" Width="440" Margin="10,15,0,0" Height="80" Tap="TextBlock_Tap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" FontSize="21" Height="580" Margin="0,100,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Restaurantnaam}" Width="440" Margin="10,15,0,0" Height="80" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Make sure Textblock_Tap or Button_Click (whichever you use) in your code behind file(PhoneApp1.LijstRestaurants.xaml.cs). Below is C# code, fairly easy to be modified to vb.net.

```
    private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {}

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        // Use datacontext to get associated ClassRestaurants

        ClassRestaurants c = (b.DataContext) as ClassRestaurants;            
    }
```

Comment: If I replace the textblock with a button, I get a debugger.break. Could you show me the code that I have to change please? Thx.

Comment: The events tap or click must be defined in your code behind file. My answer is for c# but i guess its simple enough to be adjusted to vb.net

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I give all the different buttons a different messagebox?

Comment: Cast sender of event to Button and retrieve its DataContext